# Video full screen on half of screen

Tags: video, google-chrome, video-streaming

Is it possible to have the video i'm playing in browser be played in full screen on just half of the screen?

So for example you have 1 chrome window tabbed on half of the screen with the things you want to look at. And at the other half of the screen runs the video in another chrome window but full screen (meaning just showing the video instead of all the other stuff on the website)